# Addressing Snowing (Static Noise) and Enhancing Video Quality/Size in Our App

Tags: android-camerax

We have a video recording feature in our app. However, the output quality is not very well. It is quite **snowing(static noise)** even with the default setup in which we got from: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXVideo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camerax/video/fragments/CaptureFragment.kt

val rotation = binding.cameraPreview.display.rotation

val resolutionSelector = ResolutionSelector.Builder()
.setAspectRatioStrategy(AspectRatioStrategy(screenAspectRatio, AspectRatioStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_AUTO))
.build()

val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
.setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
.setTargetVideoEncodingBitRate(2500000)
.build()

videoCapture = VideoCapture.Builder(recorder)
.setResolutionSelector(resolutionSelector)
.setTargetRotation(rotation)
.build()

In addition to that, video size is being enormous unless we set maximum bitrate. However, while setting a bitrate constraint helps us reduce the video size, but quality is becoming even worse. I am attaching a video sample so you can also check. Do you know how do I get good quality videos while maintaining the size?

Thanks!